# Statement about inequalities of two distinct solutions of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have the following initial values problem:

\begin{equation}
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
    y'(t)= t\tan(y(t) - \frac{\pi}{4})\\
    y(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}
  \end{array}\right.\,.
\end{equation}

We firstly observe that the RHS of the ODE is a function $f(y, t)$ defined in $\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} -\{\frac{3\pi}{4} + k\pi\})$ satisfying the hypothesis of the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, thus the problem locally (in an interval $I$) admits a unique solution, denoted by $y$.

Applying separation of variables gives the equation
$$
  \log|(\sin(y(t)-\frac{\pi}{4}))| = \frac{t^2}{2} + c
$$

From this result, my book states that given the constant solution of the ODE $z(t) = \frac{\pi}{4}$, and given that $y(0) = \frac{\pi}{2} > \frac{\pi}{4} = z(0)$, then
$$
  \frac{\pi}{4} < y(t) < \frac{3\pi}{4}
$$

for every $t \in I$, and proceeds to cancel the absolute value, to express $y$ in a nicer explicit form.

I don't understand how the $\frac{\pi}{4} < y(t)$ follows. I know that, if $f$ satisfied the conditions of the $\textit{global}$ existence and uniqueness theorem, we could say that two different solutions of the ODE don't intersecate, but in this case the author is using just the fact that there exists a local solution. Maybe there is a proposition I don't know, or the book is using other properties of this particular problem?

Comment: Local mean entirely on an interval of existence $I$ which is the only place you are defining a solution. There can be no intersections between solutions anywhere on that interval, whatever it is.

Comment: Suppose a solution intersected the constant solution at time $t_1\in I$. Then that violates uniqueness because you can choose $t_1$ as your location for your "initial condition"

Comment: Separately, the derivative is positive when $y$ is on the interval listed in the solution. So the function must keep increasing away from the constant solution.

Comment: Is the derivative being positive a key fact here? Because, even if the two solutions intersect in $t_1$, and of course they must be the same in an interval $I_2$ containing $t_1$, this fact alone only implies the uniqueness in $I_2$, not elsewhere. But if the derivative is strictly increasing (decreasing), then they have to be different in $I_2$ too, against the CL theorem. Is this right?

Comment: You're still not getting my first comment. The solution is *only* defined on $I_2$, there is no elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I am sorry, I am so dumb!

Answer (score 1):

Assume the inequality $\frac{\pi}{4}<y(t)$ is wrong. Using the intermediate value theorem, there must be a $t_1$ with $y(t_1)= \frac{\pi}{4}$. Look at the IVP $z'(t)=t\tan(z(t)-\frac{\pi}{4})$, $z(t_1)=\frac\pi4$, then there are two solutions: $y$ and the constant $\frac{\pi}{4}$ are solutions. By uniqueness of the IVP, $y\equiv \frac\pi4$. But $y(0)=y_0 =\frac\pi2>\frac\pi4.$